How to deal with composite operator $n$-point functions?
How does one draw Feynman diagrams for $n$-point functions of the form $$\langle\Omega|T\phi(x)^2\phi(y)|\Omega\rangle~?$$ My professor had a very short chapter explaining this but I feel like it was too short. In that chapter, he takes $$\mathcal{L}_{\text{int}} = -\frac{g}{3!}\phi^3$$ and says that the $n$-point function can be straight-forwardly extended to this case if we just treat $\phi(x)^2$ as another field operator $O(x)$. We thus get the following position space diagram:

I guess I understand what is going on here: we just treat $\phi(x)^2$ as an external point $x$ that has two legs instead of one. Is this correct? Why is this external point drawn as a cross in a circle and not a filled circle, is there a difference?
Then we move on to the momentum space diagram:

I don't really understand this. Why are the legs connecting to the composite external point labeled with momenta $p_1+k$ and $k$? How does one deduce this? Shouldn't both legs connecting to the $x$ be labelled with external momenta?
Explanation would be very much appreciated. I would however prefer that the resources treat this topic in the light of simpler examples (scalar fields and such) to make it easier to understand.

By no means does this answer the question but it's a good next step: borrowing a trick from https://hagenkleinert.de/documents/phi4/phi4.pdf, I figured out that one can write $\langle \Omega|T\phi(x)^n\phi(y)|\Omega\rangle$ as  $\int d^4x_1\dots d^4x_n \delta(x_1-x)\dots\delta(x_n-x)\langle \Omega|T\phi(x_1)\dots\phi(x_n)\phi(y)|\Omega\rangle$, compute the diagrams of $\langle \Omega|T\phi(x_1)\dots\phi(x_n)\phi(y)|\Omega\rangle$ and then simply identify all $x_i$ points with $x$ afterwards.
